# Proving $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to c } g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Here's what I need to prove:

> Suppose that $f(x)\le g(x)$ on some deleted neighborhood of the point
>   $c$ and that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ exist. Then
>   $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \le \lim_{x\to c} g(x)$.

The authors ask to prove it directly using the definition and not to use the fact that if $L > 0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for $0<|x-c|<\delta$.

Here's my attempt:

If $f(x)\le g(x)$ on some deleted neighborhood of $c$ then there's a $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that $(c-\delta_{1} , c+ \delta_{1}) \setminus \{ c \}$ is contained in that neighborhood. Let $L_{1} := \lim_{x \to c } f(x)$ and Let $L_{2} := \lim_{x \to c } g(x)$. Assume that $L_{1} > L_{2}$. Now, there are $\delta_{2} > 0$ and $\delta_{3}>0$ such that $|f(x)-L_1| < L_1-L_2$ i.e. $L_2 < f(x)$ for $0<|x-c|< \delta_2$ and similarly $g(x) < L_1 $ for $0<|x-c|< \delta_{3}$. Now for $0<|x-c|< \min \{ \delta_1 , \delta_2 , \delta_3 \} $ we have $L_2 < f(x) \le g(x) < L_1 $ which contradicts our assumption.

Is my proof fine?

Comment: I don't understand your contradiction. You assumed that $L_1>L_2$ and that's exactly what you got in the end.

Comment: If authors ask for a direct proof, then you can't prove it by contradiction, can you

Comment: Adam, direct proof means to use the definition of the limit. It doesn't mean he can't prove by contradiction.

Comment: @Mark oh, thank you. I didn't knew that

Comment: @Adam: it's quite subtle actually.  You were interpreting the statement as "prove it, directly, using the definition," but Mark and I think "prove it, directly using the definition" is the more likely reading.

Comment: @Mark it's a shame that it went unnoticed

Comment: The idea of your proof is right but I think you got a bit confused with the technical part.

Comment: It seems to me that $L_1 - L-2$ is not the right choice for $\epsilon$ to get a contradiction

Comment: Think that way: if we assume $L_1>L_2$ then you can find a small enough $\epsilon$ for which $L_1-\epsilon>L_2+\epsilon$. Now, for values of x that are very close to c you must have $L_1-\epsilon<f(x)$ and $g(x)<L_2+\epsilon$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1, L_2$ be the limits of $f,g$ respectively $\implies -\epsilon < f -L_1< \epsilon , -\epsilon <L_2-g < \epsilon\implies -2\epsilon < (f-g) + (L_2-L_1) < 2\epsilon\implies L_2-L_1> -2\epsilon +(g-f)\ge -2\epsilon$. Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have: $L_2 - L_1 \ge 0\implies L_1 \le L_2$.

Comment: (+1)  All too easy.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the upvote. Are you running for Moderator position? you should.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not running for a moderator position, but thank you for asking.  I'm flattered.